# Удаление ячейки в UITableView SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

пожалуйста с проблемой!
Есть такой метод в коде ViewController

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    let action = UIContextualAction(
        style: .destructive,
        title: "",
        handler: { (_, _, completion) in
            self.myHabitsManager.removeFromTracked(index: indexPath.row)

            AnalyticsManager.logEvent("delete_habit")

            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)

            completion(true)
        })

    if let cgImageX = UIImage(named: "delete")?.cgImage {
        action.image = ImageWithoutRender(cgImage: cgImageX, scale: UIScreen.main.nativeScale, orientation: .up)
    }

    action.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.08692767471, green: 0.1824911237, blue: 0.2160437107, alpha: 1)
    let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])
    configuration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = true

    return configuration
}
```

Анимация удаления отрабатывает, данные из базы данных удаляются, но при нажатии на кнопку в ячейке (любой из тех что остались) происходит действие (смена картинки на кнопке) с ячейкой ниже.

[image: Экран]

Comment: Почему вы думаете что виновата функция удаления? Что происходит когда просто нажимаете на кнопку? Можно код нажатия на кнопку?

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите это видео, здесь рассказывают про table view , и как удалять правильно cell тоже.
Возможно вы просто что то упустили методов.
[TableView-video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qmu_GvVwCi0)